# Is custom input module a good practice in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

App I'm building, all inputs look exactly the same (Design wise).

I am feeling I am repeating my self every time with the following lines:

**HTML**

```
<div class="myInputContainer">
  <input
    type="text"
    class="myInputView-input"
    aria-label="login_email"
    placeholder="Filter Menu Items..."/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myInputContainer {
  @extend %input-like-container;
}

.myInputView-input {
  @extend %input-like;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I am considering creating an Input module and using it instead of repeating code

```
<my-input placeholder="foo">
```

**My question is:**

Is this good practice to create a module of a base UI component? (Using module is the only way all other modules can import and use it)

All examples applications I see use only default `<input>` and I am not really sure why.

Thanks.

Comment: This will make form binding tedious. I would advise you to reserve this approach for customized inputs.

Comment: @zer0 Good point about form binding... Thank you

Comment: I think it is a very good practice just look at the popularity of Angular Material or ngx-bootstrap they all utilize that pattern.

Comment: Have you tried using NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR for building custom input controls. You can bind the data to forms same as you do form other contols

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about angular - yes. Angular is a component-based framework. So here how we do in our project. We have a base module for common components.

`myapp.common`

I have a bunch of custom components in it.

`myapp.common.input`

`myapp.common.select`

Check out [what](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) AngularJS team suggest:

> While the example above is simple, it will not scale to large
>   applications. Instead we recommend that you break your application to
>   multiple modules like this:
>
> 1. A module for each feature
> 2. A module for each reusable component (especially directives and filters)
> 3. And an application level module which depends on the above modules and contains any initialization code.

Here is how my input component looks like:

```
(function () {
  /* @ngInject */
  function InputComponent() {
    const ctrl = this;

    ctrl.$onInit = function () {
      ctrl.ngModel.$render = function () {
        ctrl.innerModel = ctrl.ngModel.$viewValue;
      };
      ctrl.onChange = function () {
        ctrl.ngModel.$setViewValue(ctrl.innerModel);
      };
    };
  }

  angular
    .module('myapp.common.input')
    .component('myappInput', {
      controller: InputComponent,
      require: {
        ngModel: 'ngModel',
      },
      bindings: {
        placeholder: '@',
        type: '@',
        title: '@',
      },
      template:
        `<div class="form-group">
          <label class="myapp-input-title">
            {{ ::$ctrl.title }}
          </label>
          <input
            ng-model="$ctrl.innerModel"
            ng-change="$ctrl.onChange()"
            placeholder="{{ ::$ctrl.placeholder }}"
            type="{{ ::$ctrl.type }}"
         </div>`,
    });
}());
```

The little snippet in `$onInit` is required to bind custom component ngModel to input model.

So now I simply use this

`<myapp-input ng-model='modelName'></myapp-input>`

Here are some benefits:

1. All your components looks the same, you are not afraid to forget class or something
2. Easy to extend - you already have a component and all its code concentrated in one place.
3. Easy to write unit tests - you just including `myapp.custom.input` to the test suite and make sure that you testing this exact peace of code
4. Easy to change design - you just have to change it one place and the changes will be automatically applied to the whole project.